# Error in Codeigniter Folder Structure... Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, cpanel

I changed the folder tree of my CI app on Cpanel from the following path below but i got this error:

**Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php**

> Previous Folder Structure:

```
root
 application
 public_html
   site_folder
     system
    .htaccess
```

> Current Folder Structure:

```
root 
  public_html
    site_folder
      application
      system
     .htaccess
```

**index.php**

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');

switch (ENVIRONMENT)
```

{
case 'development':
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
break;

```
case 'testing':
case 'production':
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.2', '>='))
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    }
    else
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
    }
break;

default:
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
    exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
```

}

```
$system_path = 'system';

$application_folder = 'application';

$view_folder = '';

    if (defined('STDIN'))
{
    chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
}

if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
{
    $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
else
{
    // Ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = strtr(
        rtrim($system_path, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}

// Is the system path correct?
if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}

    // The name of THIS file
define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

// Path to the system directory
define('BASEPATH', $system_path);

// Path to the front controller (this file) directory
define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Name of the "system" directory
define('SYSDIR', basename(BASEPATH));

// The path to the "application" directory
if (is_dir($application_folder))
{
    if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $application_folder = $_temp;
    }
    else
    {
        $application_folder = strtr(
            rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
}
elseif (is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
{
    $application_folder = BASEPATH.strtr(
        trim($application_folder, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    );
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}

define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// The path to the "views" directory
if ( ! isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
{
    $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
}
elseif (is_dir($view_folder))
{
    if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $view_folder = $_temp;
    }
    else
    {
        $view_folder = strtr(
            rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
}
elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
{
    $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr(
        trim($view_folder, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    );
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}

define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you show where index.php was (and is) in the old and new heirarchies?

Comment: thanks for replying John, it is in the new, inside site_folder...

Comment: Look at what CI is testing for the App folder - right above the error/exit - die(BASEPATH.$application_folder). Does that give a clue? When you changed the structure of your app, did you also change the server path you're using to access it?

Comment: currently i set it in old heirarchy, and i play and commented someline in the index.php... but the weird thing is it doestn give any error.... i try to remove all code in index.php but the site still up and running... but when i set it in the new heirarchy, then.. the error bug will show... weird... it seems the index is useless when it is set in the first heirarchy